# How to Delete an S3 Object by ETag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using AmazonS3 SDK how can we delete an S3 Object using the key(i.e. file name) and eTag for the object ?

We can get file by eTag leveraging below code

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key);
request.setMatchingETagConstraints(Collections.singletonList(eTag));
```

do we have similar API to delete an Object from S3 ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no `setMatchingETagConstraints` method for deleteobjectrequest. You will need to get the key first as you describe.